# Python package built with Poetry does not install supporting data files

Tags: python-packaging, python-poetry

I'm writing a Python package (assume it's "mypkg") and using Poetry to build the distributable wheel/tar.gz files for installation by the end users. But when I install the package using `pip install mypkg-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl` it does not install the supporting files, such as the tests and CLI scripts. I've attempted to follow all the standard best practices for organizing a package, but I've clearly missed somet fundamental interaction between the package structure and how poetry/setuptools is interacting with it all.

Here is the package structure:

```
mypkg
¦   .gitignore
¦   pyproject.toml
¦   README.txt
¦       
+---mypkg
¦   ¦   a.py
¦   ¦   b.py
¦   ¦   __init__.py
¦   ¦   
¦   +---styles
¦   ¦       mypkg c.exp
¦   ¦       mypkg d.exp
¦           
+---data
¦       e.json
¦       f.json
¦       
+---dist
¦       mypkg-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl
¦       mypkg-0.2.0.tar.gz
¦       
+---docs
¦       User Guide.pdf
¦       
+---LICENSE
¦       License.rtf
¦       ThirdParty.rtf
¦       
+---scripts
¦       other.py
¦       run_mypkg.py
¦       
+---tests
¦   ¦   conftest.py
¦   ¦   test_g.py
¦   ¦   test_h.py
¦   ¦   __init__.py
¦   ¦               
¦   +---data
¦   ¦   +---g
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   otherfile.txt
¦   ¦   ¦               
¦   ¦   +---h
¦   ¦       ¦   differentfile.txt
```

where

- mypkg - core source code and some mandatory supporting files in the `styles` directory.
- data - supporting data files that will be read by the CLI scripts.
- docs - User guide, etc.
- scripts -  some CLI scripts that a user can run to exercise the routines in mypkg
- tests - are the various pytest files/functions.

The contents of my pyproject.toml file are

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "mypkg"
version = "0.2.0"
description = "stuff"
license = "Proprietary"
authors = ["Me <support@test.com>"]
readme = "README.txt"
include = [
    { path = "data"},
    { path = "scripts"},
    { path = "tests"},
    { path = "LICENSE"},
    { path = "docs/*.pdf"},
]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
numpy = "^1.23.2"
pandas = "^1.4.4"
portion = "^2.3.0"
scipy = "^1.9.1"
plotly = "^5.10.0"
pytest = "^7.2.0"
tqdm = "^4.64.1"
jsonpickle = "^2.2.0"

[tool.pytest.ini_options]
log_cli = true
log_cli_level = "INFO"
minversion = "6.0"
addopts = "-ra"
testpaths = [
    "tests",
]

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

When I run `poetry build` it succcesfully builds the wheel, etc. I can examine the .tar.gz file in 7zip and confirm that the contents are:

```
mypkg-0.2.0
    ¦   PKG-INFO
    ¦   pyproject.toml
    ¦   README.txt
    ¦   setup.py
    ¦       
    +---mypkg
    ¦   ¦   a.py
    ¦   ¦   b.py
    ¦   ¦   __init__.py
    ¦   ¦  
    ¦   +---styles
    ¦   ¦       mypkg c.exp
    ¦   ¦       mypkg d.exp
    +---data
    ¦       e.json
    ¦       f.json
    ¦       
    +---docs
    ¦       User Guide.pdf
    ¦       
    +---LICENSE
    ¦       License.rtf
    ¦       ThirdParty.rtf
    ¦       
    +---scripts
    ¦       other.py
    ¦       run_mypkg.py
    ¦       
    +---tests
    ¦   ¦   conftest.py
    ¦   ¦   test_g.py
    ¦   ¦   test_h.py
    ¦   ¦   __init__.py
    ¦   ¦               
    ¦   +---data
    ¦   ¦   +---g
    ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   otherfile.txt
    ¦   ¦   ¦               
    ¦   ¦   +---h
    ¦   ¦       ¦   differentfile.txt
```

So it looks like poetry is grabbing all the files I've asked it to. I install into a test conda environent using
`pip install mypkg-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl`.  Then looking at the `C:\Users\me\anaconda3\envs\test\Lib\site-packages\mypkg` I only see the core source code and the `styles` directory. I can't find the top level tests|scripts|data directories anywhere. The docs got installed under `C:\Users\me\anaconda3\envs\test\Lib\site-packages\docs`.

The setup.py file that was created by poetry in the wheel looks like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from setuptools import setup

packages = \
['mypkg']

package_data = \
{'': ['*'], 'mypkg': ['styles/*']}

install_requires = \
['jsonpickle>=2.2.0,<3.0.0',
 'numpy>=1.23.2,<2.0.0',
 'pandas>=1.4.4,<2.0.0',
 'plotly>=5.10.0,<6.0.0',
 'portion>=2.3.0,<3.0.0',
 'pytest>=7.2.0,<8.0.0',
 'scipy>=1.9.1,<2.0.0',
 'tqdm>=4.64.1,<5.0.0']

setup_kwargs = {
    'name': 'cram',
    'version': '0.2.0',
    'description': 'stuff',
    'author': 'Me',
    'author_email': '<support@test.com>',
    'maintainer': 'None',
    'maintainer_email': 'None',
    'packages': packages,
    'package_data': package_data,
    'install_requires': install_requires,
    'python_requires': '>=3.8,<4.0',
}


setup(**setup_kwargs)
```

Judging by this, it appears that setup.py is only grabbing the stuff directory under mypkg, which is consistent with the observed behavior. The desired outcome is to have the installed package include the tests | scripts | docs directories.

For export control reasons, I can't publish the package to PyPi - so everything has to be self-contained. As far as I can tell my options are:

1. Move everything under mypkg, but that seems to be going against best practices for organizing the package
2. Fix some fundamental flaw in how my pyproject.toml file is setup that is resulting in the setup.py not doing "the right" thing?

Thanks!

Comment: You should move `data` directory to `mypkg/data`. This will make everything easier.

Comment: @sinoroc  (a) why is it easier  (b) _must_ the `data` be under the `mypkg` ? ie. it's reasonable to consider the data-files to _not_ logically belong to a python package but rather be independent of the code

Comment: As soon as you need the data during runtime, they are not independent of the code anymore and therefor belonging to the package itself. It's normal that a package consists of more than just python files.

Comment: Moving the `data` under `mypkg` makes sense. I'd also like to ship the tests and docs with the package so that once they have installed it, they can run the self-test and see the documentation. So it looks like I'll need to put those under `mypgk` as well then?

Comment: As far as I know, it is not a common practice to install self-tests. The common practice is to have the tests in the source distribution (_sdist_), but not in the wheel. This way who wants to run the self tests can (by getting the sdist) but it is not the default behavior (since the default behavior is to install from wheel). -- Same for docs, although it seems weird. -- But you have to know that Python packaging is quite limited (on purpose), if you want advanced things (such as installing user docs), you might want to use native packaging (apt/deb, rpm/yum, msi, flatpak, etc.).

Comment: Gotcha. I think that's where my confusion is coming from. I see the files I want/where I want in the tar.gz but they aren't in the wheel. Which appears to be by design. If you resubmit as an answer I'll mark it as such.

Comment: After a ridiculous amount of searching, I finally found this https://jwodder.github.io/kbits/posts/pypkg-mistakes/ which describes in great details the pros and cons of the various things I was trying to do.